# Which Acoustic Indices are useful for low-frequency recordings?

Tags: acoustic-indices

We are currently analysing soil recordings using Acoustic Indices, and applying Acoustic Complexity Index to the 0-2 kHz range (there is no useful signal above this upper limit).  The Acoustic Complexity Index (ACI) is as proposed in Pieretti, Farina & Morri (2011) A new methodology to infer the singing activity of an avian community: The Acoustic Complexity Index (ACI) Ecological Indicators 11(3)

Which other Indices could be usefully applied below the 2 kHz upper limit?

Is anyone aware of studies applying Indices in narrow frequency ranges like this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you include a reference to the 'acoustic indices' and 'acoustic complexity index' that you're referring to? It might be helpful if you explained a bit more about your research questions so community members might be able to give you other suggestions.

Comment: Thanks.  The Acoustic Complexity Index (ACI) is as proposed in Pieretti, Farina & Morri (2011) A new methodology to infer the singing activity of an avian community: The Acoustic Complexity Index (ACI) Ecological Indicators 11(3)

Answer (score 3):

In the noise monitoring world, we regularly look at [Third-octave Levels](https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/third-octave) (TOLs) to describe the soundscape, especially in the lower frequencies you are interested in. We use them to help describe increases in anthropogenic pressure

The linked article can be found in:

Meggitt, J. A. R. (2017). On in-situ methodologies for the characterisation and simulation of vibro-acoustic assemblies. University of Salford (United Kingdom).

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you can calculate any acoustic index just on the smaller bin - ie get seewave to calculate for example ACI in the limited range.

Or downsample to 4 or 8 khz and then run your normal scripts in R.

Comment: Please avoid using unexplained abbreviations. Not all users will know what ACI is.

Comment: Thanks Simon.  My thought/concern is that by reducing the analysis bandwidth of the Acoustic Complexity Index, I am also reducing the number of frequency bins used in the index (to only two?), and thereby reducing the power of the index??

Comment: We have to ask Jerome Sueur. I think the number of frequency bins are preserved. Definitely if you downsample ahead of time they should be preserved.

Comment: Number of bins won't be preserved _unless_ you downsample, or you change the window length to match the equivalent spectrogram resolution found in the original recording.

Answer (score 2):

You might check out the methods used in these papers -

[Non-native species change the tune of tundra soils: Novel access to soundscapes of the Arctic earthworm invasion](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S004896972203073X).

[Sounding Soil: An Acoustic, Ecological & Artistic Investigation of Soil Life](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/335826299_Sounding_Soil_An_Acoustic_Ecological_Artistic_Investigation_of_Soil_Life)

And as alluded to in previous comments, you could also just run a bandpass filter and calculate the indices on the filtered recordings.